# Print an array value when its key matches with a variable (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

I have a "album.php" page with four albums; when you click on one of them it links to "gallery.php" showing the photos of that specific album. 
Now I would like to put a specific title in "gallery.php" depending on the album clicked by the user and I would like to do it in a nice and clean way. 
gallery.php:

```
$query_url = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$pageID = substr($query_url, 6);
$album_title = array("album1" => "title1",
                     "album2" => "title2",
                     "album3" => "title3");
while($album_title[KEY] = $pageID)
  {
   echo '<div id="album_title">
           <h2 class="body_text">'.$album_title[VALUE].'</h2>
         </div>';
  }
```

I thought something like that instead of the less dynamic:

```
if($pageID = "album1")
  {echo "title1";}
if($pageID = "album2")
  {echo "title2";}
etc.
```

My problem is that I don't know how I could "say":

```
when(array[KEY] = $pageID)
  {
   echo 'the correspondent array[VALUE]';
  }
```

Thanks everyone!

[EDIT] Voting negatively without an explication doesn't solve any problem in this world, mate. Was probably 'cause I used "while" instead of "foreach" in my example? I know about its existence but I tried multiple times with it also without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provinding $pageID is something like "album1" you wouldn't need any loop:

```
echo '<div id="album_title">
  <h2 class="body_text">' . $album_title[$pageID] . '</h2>
</div>';
```

Check it out.

Comment: Now I understood a lot more on how an array works. Thanks!